# Reproduce XML with attributes using XSLT 2.0 & Grouping one element

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm a newbie to XSLT and had to group/sum one element as a single employee may have two rows of data. I was able to achieve that using  tag and sum(current-group()) function. The input xml had attributes and along with the prior need also have to reproduce the xml attributes in the resulting output xml.

```
**Sample XML:**
<ws:Review>
  <ws:Employee>
    <ws:EmpID>12345</ws:EmpID>
    <ws:Amount>4</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Amount>5</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Currency Descriptor="IDR">
      <ws:ID ws:type="AID">9464cef721784d6ab96eaad1b366f6e7</ws:ID>
      <ws:ID ws:type="Currency_ID">IDR</ws:ID>
    </ws:Currency>
  </ws:Employee>
  <ws:Employee>
    <ws:EmpID>12345</ws:EmpID>
    <ws:Amount>6</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Currency Descriptor="IDR">
      <ws:ID ws:type="AID">9464cef721784d6ab96eaad1b366f6e7</ws:ID>
      <ws:ID ws:type="Currency_ID">IDR</ws:ID>
    </ws:Currency>
  </ws:Employee>
  <ws:Employee>
    <ws:EmpID>23456</ws:EmpID>
    <ws:Amount>4</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Currency Descriptor="GBP">
      <ws:ID ws:type="AID">9464cef721784d6ab96eaad1b366f6e5</ws:ID>
      <ws:ID ws:type="Currency_ID">GBP</ws:ID>
    </ws:Currency>
  </ws:Employee>
  <ws:Employee>
    <ws:EmpID>34567</ws:EmpID>
    <ws:Amount>4</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Amount>5</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Currency Descriptor="USD">
      <ws:ID ws:type="AID">9464cef721784d6ab96eaad1b366f679</ws:ID>
      <ws:ID ws:type="Currency_ID">USD</ws:ID>
    </ws:Currency>
  </ws:Employee>
</ws:Review>
```

Expected Output:

```
<ws:Review>
  <ws:Employee>
    <ws:EmpID>12345</ws:EmpID>
    <ws:Amount>15</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Currency Descriptor="IDR">
      <ws:ID ws:type="AID">9464cef721784d6ab96eaad1b366f6e7</ws:ID>
      <ws:ID ws:type="Currency_ID">IDR</ws:ID>
    </ws:Currency>
  </ws:Employee>
  <ws:Employee>
    <ws:EmpID>23456</ws:EmpID>
    <ws:Amount>4</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Currency Descriptor="GBP">
      <ws:ID ws:type="AID">9464cef721784d6ab96eaad1b366f6e7</ws:ID>
      <ws:ID ws:type="Currency_ID">GBP</ws:ID>
    </ws:Currency>
  </ws:Employee>
  <ws:Employee>
    <ws:EmpID>34567</ws:EmpID>
    <ws:Amount>9</ws:Amount>
    <ws:Currency Descriptor="USD">
      <ws:ID ws:type="AID">9464cef721784d6ab96eaad1b366f6e7</ws:ID>
      <ws:ID ws:type="Currency_ID">USD</ws:ID>
    </ws:Currency>
  </ws:Employee>
</ws:Review>
```

XSL that I've written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ws="namespace" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <ws:Review>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="ws:Review/ws:Employee" group-by="ws:Employee/ws:EmpID>
      <ws:EmpID><xsl:value-of select="ws:Employee/ws:EmpID"/></ws:EmpID>
      <ws:Currency><xsl:value-of select="ws:Employee/ws:Currency/@ws:Descriptor"/></ws:Currency>
      <ws:Amount><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/ws:Employee/ws:Amount)"/></ws:Amount>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </ws:Review>
</xsl:template>
```

Can someone help me modify the current xsl such that the attributes are carried forward? I would be glad for any assistance provided.

Thanks!
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would push the elements to the identity transformation, see http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqy which does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:ws="http://example.com/">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ws:Review">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="ws:Employee" group-by="ws:EmpID">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ws:EmpID"/>
                    <ws:Amount><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/ws:Amount)"/></ws:Amount>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (ws:EmpID, ws:Amount)"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Martin, thank you very much. Worked perfectly well and appreciate your assistance!